# How vulnerable is ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) over wifi now that WPA2 is cracked?

Tags: wifi, android, wpa2, krack

How vulnerable is ADB over wifi now that WPA2 is cracked? Could hackers MITM/inject commands I am sending from my pc to my phone? My Windows PC is patched but no official fix is available for Android yet.

Answer (score 1):

Some clarification: WPA2 ***is not cracked***. The WPA2 protocol is mathematically secure however an implementation oversight in a few OS's allows for some nasty consequences with a local attacker. WPA2 can continue to be used for the foreseeable future so long as you update your devices.

ADB is fine so long as your device is >4.2.2 (which as far as I know is the only vulnerable range for Android?).

> ADB Authentication. Since Android 4.2.2, connections to ADB are authenticated with an RSA keypair. This prevents unauthorized use of ADB where the attacker has physical access to a device.

Unless the attacker steals the keypair their only option is to trick you into authorizing a new device which really isn't anything new or novel.

Source: https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43